# How to show Maven multi-module project's nested-modules as top level modules in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, ide

I am using IntelliJIDEA 14 and recently switched from Eclipse.
In Eclipse we can import any of the nested modules as top level projects and I am trying to do the same in IntelliJ.

I am trying to open a maven multi-module project and want to see the nested modules as top level modules in IntelliJ.

But when I Open/Import Root Maven module (pom package type) only the root module is being displayed as top level project and all the nested modules are being displayed under root module directory hierarchy.

Why I need this is my maven project has 3 to 4 levels of hierarchy(Broadleaf application). Navigating through all these modules only from root directory is painful.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you referring to the `Maven Projects` view? You can tweak it to discard hierarchy view by unselecting `Group modules`. Click on that little icon on the right to get the popup.

[image]

Edit:

When referring to `Projects` view, one can change the the facet to `Packages`:

[image]

Comment: No, I am referring to Projects View.

Comment: Then you should be able to switch to the `Packages` facet of it

Comment: Yeah, when I switch to Packages facets I am seeing all the child modules except pom type modules. Thank you!